# Ionic: How to display content from a template without using abstract definition

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Quite a simple question, but still I'm struggeling with it. Basically the idea was to have a login page that works without any `ion-side-menus`. After logging in the `ion-side-menus` will be defined as `abstract` and it will work as in [the starter example](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu) (see [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0RXSDB?p=preview)).

I've created a demo to demonstrate what's not working: [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/koHYjvr6sVFQ0SZQPr38?p=preview)

These are the files:

index.html

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
    <link data-require="ionic@1.0.0-beta.1" data-semver="1.0.0-beta.1" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/css/ionic.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="ionic@1.0.0-beta.1" data-semver="1.0.0-beta.1" src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="has-header"></ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // routing
    $stateProvider

    // start
    .state('start', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'start.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

start.html

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content scroll="false">
        <div class="intro padding row row-center">
            <div class="col">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {
})
```

The content from start.html needs to show up when openen the `/` but nothing is there. I guess I#m doing something wrong in `index.html` propably using the wrong tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
<ion-nav-view class="has-header"></ion-nav-view>
```

Instead of `<ion-content>` inside `index.html`.

Update plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qdw2aAYM8UxI9nS71hkl?p=preview

Comment: Obviously its just enough to use `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>`. Thanks!